# Rails Active Model Serializer — need to manipulate rendered json prior to send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

So here's a fun one — I have a controller method that returns a list of "resumable" objects based on some rules.  But, there are criteria i can't include in a single database query — so, I'd like to render out the "base" resumable list, and then essentially run a filter on it prior to returning to the client.

In other words, what I'm trying to do is:

```
sessions = ended_sessions.where("current_date <= (created_at + interval '12 hours')")

json = JSON.parse(SessionResumeSerializer.new(sessions).as_json)

json.each do |session|
 # additional processing
end
```

Anyway, `SessionResumeSerializer.new(sessions).as_json` totally doesn't work, throwing an :

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'read_attribute_for_serialization' for  <ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ffa164b0ce0>` error.

I'm clearly confused about how this is supposed to work — seems completely intuitive that the initializer would take a relation and render it out.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your "sessions" variable refers to an array and not a session object. What you are doing would have worked perfectly for a single session (of class SessionResume) but for an array you need to do something like the following:

```
sessions = ended_sessions.where("current_date <= (created_at + interval '12 hours')")
json     = JSON.parse(ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(sessions).as_json)

json.each do |session|
    # additional processing
end
```

Note that you need to use **ActiveModel::ArraySerializer** rather than the class specific, single-object serializer.

Comment: I like this — great solve!  I ended up taking a slightly different direction and looped over the sessions relation, did my processing at THAT point, and then added to an array of single object serializers which are then returned.  Works great, and keeps the actual json serialization later in the process, as it should be.  Giving you the answer anyway as it would've also worked.  thx